# Can't subclass CPTGraphHostingView in CorePlot anymore (v2.3)?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, subclass, core-plot

I have just updated my app with the latest release of CorePlot (v2.3, I was running a version < 2.0 previously).
I did not get any errors however my graphs have disappeared.
I used to subclass CPTGraphHostingView by doing something like:

```
final class GraphView: CPTGraphHostingView, CPTPlotDataSource {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configureGraph()
        ...
}

fileprivate func configureGraph() {
    // Graph theme
    graph.apply(CPTTheme(named: .plainWhiteTheme))

    // Hosting view
    self.hostedGraph = graph

    // Plot Space
    plotSpace = graph.defaultPlotSpace as! CPTXYPlotSpace
}
```

I noticed that subclassing a UIView instead of CPTGraphHostingView works with the new release:

```
final class GraphView: UIView, CPTPlotDataSource {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configureGraph()
        ...
}

fileprivate func configureGraph() {
    // Graph theme
    graph.apply(CPTTheme(named: .plainWhiteTheme))

    // Hosting view
    let hostingView = CPTGraphHostingView(frame: self.frame)
    hostingView.hostedGraph = graph
    self.addSubview(hostingView)

    // Plot Space
    plotSpace = graph.defaultPlotSpace as! CPTXYPlotSpace
}
```

It is fine in most of cases, but one of my graph is located on a ScrollView (paging enabled) so getting `self.frame` for the `hostingView` in that case is not easy.
Am I missing something in this new release?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on Eric answer, I removed the subclass and simply added constraints to the hosting view:

```
fileprivate func configureGraph() {
    // Graph theme
    graph.apply(CPTTheme(named: .plainWhiteTheme))

    let hostingView = CPTGraphHostingView(frame: self.bounds)
    hostingView.hostedGraph = self.graph
    self.addSubview(hostingView)
    hostingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        hostingView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
        hostingView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        hostingView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1),
        hostingView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1)
    ])

    // Plot Space
    plotSpace = graph.defaultPlotSpace as! CPTXYPlotSpace
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `bounds` when sizing the hosting view rather than the `frame`.

```
let hostingView = CPTGraphHostingView(frame: self.bounds)
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. So subclassing CPTGraphHostingView is not the way to go anymore? I did not try yet, but I guess that I have to handle the bounds when changing the view orientation or re-sizing, right?

Comment: It never was. The setup logic belongs in a view controller. The hosting view is just another view. You position it on screen like any other. The graph will always fill the hosting view and will automatically change size when the hosting view does.